# Angularjs 1.2 adds empty option in select

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I have a dropdown that gets its items from database. The default value to be selected in this dropdown is retrieved from a cookie. 
The problem is,
1. there is an empty option tag as the first option and also,
2. the default value is not selected.
There is no issue at all when I use `v1.3.16`. This happens when using `v1.2.0`. (I have to use only v1.2.0)
How to fix this.

**ASPX:**

```
<select id="ddlItems" data-ng-model="ItemId">
 <option value="-1">-- All Circles --</option>
 <option data-ng-repeat="item in Items" value="{{item.AreaCode}}" 
  data-ng-selected="item.AreaCode==ItemId">{{item.AreaName}}</option>
</select>
```

**Ctrl.js:**

```
var promise = MyFactory.GetItems();
promise.then(function (success) {
 if (success.data != null && success.data != '') {
  var data = success.data;
  $scope.Items = data.lstItems; //bind items to dropdown      
  $scope.ItemId = itemIdFromCookie; //select default value
  alert(itemIdFromCookie); //it pops -1                       
 }
 else {
  console.log(success.data);
 }
}
```

**Rendered HTML:**

```
<select id="ddlItems" data-ng-model="ItemId">
 <option value="? string:"-1" ?"></option>
 <option value="-1">-- All Circles --</option>
 //...other options
</select>
```

Comment: @ErikE.I'm sure, because I have posted a working code.

Comment: I tried your way. Doesnt bind items at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **[ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)** instead

Like this

```
<select id="ddlItems" 
     data-ng-model="ItemId" 
     ng-options="item.AreaCode as item.AreaName for item in Items">
 <option value="-1">-- All Circles --</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That did not work. There is still an emtpy option tag and the first option '--All Circles--' is removed.

Comment: can you provide fiddle ?? @Qwerty

Answer (score 1):

This happens because`data-ng-model="ItemId"` is empty when your model is **App** is Loaded.

To Have some initial value. you can put default value in `ng-init`

For Ex : **`data-ng-init='data-ng-model="--SELECT--";'`**

Or per your Array list Item which you are getting from database set one of the values.

Remember **init** will get triggered b/f you complete the Ajax Call.

Comment: I get the items & also the desired ItemId from the ajax call. Could you please suggest, how I proceed in this case.

Comment: After items are bind to the select set data-ng-model value.

Comment: Can  you please jsfiddle it